# How to set up the ODBC environment in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, oracle, unixodbc, otl

When unixODBC (odbc.ini and odbcinst.in) files are under /usr/local/etc/. My application works fine.

I deleted the unixODBC files from /usr/local/etc/ and copied .odbc.ini and .odbcinst.ini files under home/$USER directory.  I have done the environment variable setup for the .odbc.ini files.  But while connecting to the database using the OTL library, I am getting the following error

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Which distribution are you using? Did you compile unixODBC yourself? Did you double check that the ~/.odbc.ini contains a section for the data source name used in your application? Does the file belong to the correct user (permissions)? Are you running your app as the correct user?

Comment: unixODBC is working fine for me with a ~/.odbc.ini and an empty /etc/odbc/odbc.ini

Comment: BTW: You can try to run your application using `strace` and search in the output for `odbc.ini`. This helped me to identify issues before.

Comment: sorry for the late response, The issue is with my application. After lot of debugging and research, I found that my application is not  getting the oracle driver libraries, I have moved the oracle driver library path in the environment script and it started working fine with .odbc.ini

Comment: You should make this comment an answer and accept it as the solution.